# How to use View Binding with Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-viewbinding

I have a activity_main.xml file which looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_linear_layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/dice_text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/roll"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So when i try to create a view binding and use it in Activity file,
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val root = binding.root
    setContentView(root.main_linear_layout)
    buttonClicked()
}

fun buttonClicked(): Unit {
    val roll_button = binding.mainLinearLayout.roll_button
    val text = binding.mainLinearLayout.dice_text
    roll_button.setOnClickListener {
        var randomNumber = Random().nextInt(6)+1
        text.text = randomNumber.toString()
    }
}
```

}

i have some issues. Naturally since the Linear Layout has layout_gravity set to center, it should be centered in the screen, both vertically and horizontally. This is the case in the design editor of the xml which is how it is supposed to be.

But when i run the app, in my phone both the text and button, aligns center_horizontal but not vertically.

I tried giving center_vertical also but doesn't work.

But if i don't use the view binding and use findViewById , it works fine.

Edit: I have removed the mainLinearLayout from the binding. So its just

```
setContentView(root)
```

I doesn't work.[This is how i want it to be and this is how it is present in the Design View of the xml ( I have removed text and added Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve4wu.png)

But, when i run it, i get this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAeaL.png)

P.S I have just started learning android development

Comment: Try using `android:gravity="center"` on the LinearLayout. `layout_gravity` is for children of view groups, but LinearLayout is the root view here.

Comment: You can just use setContentView(root).  Try it.

Comment: Also, binding.roll_button and binding.dice_text are sufficient, you dont have to access the parent layout to access the child.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
android:gravity = "center"
```

worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val root = binding.root
    setContentView(root)
    buttonClicked()
}
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities